# convert dict to xml with distinct namespaces

Tags: python

I have dictionary like:

```
dict1 = {"properties xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip": {"property": [{"name": "admin-state", "config xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip": {"name": "admin-state", "value xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip": "DISABLED"}}]}}
args = collections.OrderedDict(dict1)
```

I am trying to convert it to xml keeping namespaces intact.

I tried converting dictionary to ordered Dictionary and then using dict2xml converting it to xml

```
dict1 = {"properties xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip": {"property": [{"name": "admin-state", "config xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip": {"name": "admin-state", "value xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip": "DISABLED"}}]}}
args = collections.OrderedDict(dict1)
args = collections.OrderedDict(dict1)
dictXml = str(dict2xml(args,indent='')).replace('\n','')
```

output coming is :

```
'<properties_xmlns_http:__openconfig.net_yang_interfaces_ip><property><config_xmlns_http:__openconfig.net_yang_interfaces_ip><name>admin-state</name><value_xmlns_http:__openconfig.net_yang_interfaces_ip>DISABLED</value_xmlns_http:__openconfig.net_yang_interfaces_ip></config_xmlns_http:__openconfig.net_yang_interfaces_ip><name>admin-state</name></property></properties_xmlns_http:__openconfig.net_yang_interfaces_ip>'
```

Expected output is:

```
<properties xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip><property><config xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip><name>admin-state</name><value xmlns=http://openconfig.net/yang/interfaces/ip>DISABLED</value></config><name>admin-state</name></property></properties>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this: https://github.com/watzon/xmler It is an alternative that supports namespace:

```
import dict2xml from xmler

myDict = {
    "RootTag": {                        # The root tag. Will not necessarily be root. (see #customRoot)
        "@ns": "soapenv",           # The namespace for the RootTag. The RootTag will appear as <soapenv:RootTag ...>
        "@attrs": {                     # @attrs takes a dictionary. each key-value pair will become an attribute
            { "xmlns:soapenv": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" }
        },
        "childTag": {
            "@attrs": {
                "someAttribute": "colors are nice"
            },
            "grandchild": "This is a text tag"
        }
    }
}

print(dict2xml(myDict, pretty=True, customRoot=None)
```

Returns

```
<soapenv:RootTag xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <childTag someAttribute="colors are nice">
        <grandchild>This is a text tag</grandchild>
    </childTag>
</soapenv:RootTag>
```

(from the github)